# C# - Dealing with many-to-many without an ORM

Tags: c#, wpf, many-to-many, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I have two database tables that are many-to-many

**tblBook**
idBook
Title
Writer
ect...

**tblBookGenre**
id
idBook
idGenre

**tblGenre**
idGenre
NameGenre

And 
**tblBook**
idBook
Title
Writer
ect...

**tblBookTag**
id
idBook
idGenre

**tblTag**
idTag
NameTag

I map them like this

```
 public class Book:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Connection con = new Connection();

        private int _idBook;
        private string _title;
        private List<Genre> _genres;
        private List<Tag> _tag;
        private ObservableCollection<Book> _books;

      public int IdBook
        {
            get { return _idBook; }
            set { _idBook = value; }
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }

       public List<Genre> Genres
        {
            get { return _genres; }
            set { _genres = value; }
        }

        public List<Tag> Tags
        {
            get { return _tag; }
            set { _tag = value; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
        {
            get { return _books; }
            set { _books = value; }
        }
       public Book()
        {
            Tags = new List<Tag>();
            Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
            Genres = new List<Genre>();
        }
```

I use a sqlcommand and reader to read from the database

```
        public ObservableCollection<Book> GetBooks()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con.con;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT idBook,Title FROM tblBook WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY b.idBook";
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    Book book = new Book();

                    var id = Convert.ToInt32(rd["IdBook"]);
                    var title = rd["Title"].ToString();

                    book.IdBook = id;
                    book.Title = title;

                    List<Tag> tags = GetTagsThatMatch(id);
                    book.Tags = tags;
                    book.Genres = GetGenresThatMatch(id);

                    Books.Add(book);

                }
                rd.Close();
            }
            con.Close();
            return Books;
        }
```

```
        public ObservableCollection<Tag> GetTagsThatMatch(int id)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con.con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT t.IdTag,t.Name FROM tblTag t LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBookTag bt ON bt.idTag = t.idTag WHERE bt.idBook = @ID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    Tag tag = new Tag();
                    tag.IdTag = Convert.ToInt32(rd["IdTag"]);
                    tag.Name = rd["Name"].ToString();
                    Tags.Add(tag);
                }
            }
            return Tags;
        }
```

```
        public List<Genre> GetGenresThatMatch(int id)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con.con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT g.Name FROM tblGenre g LEFT JOIN tblBookGenre bg ON g.IdGenre = bg.IdGenre LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBook b ON bg.IdBook = b.IdBook WHERE b.IdBook = @Id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    Genre genre = new Genre();
                    genre.Name = rd["Name"].ToString();
                    Genres.Add(genre);
                }
            }
            return Genres;
        }
```

Problem is it displays all genres and tags for all books

Book 1 - Genre 1, Genre 2, Genre3
       - Tag1, Tag2, Tag3

Book 2 - Genre 1, Genre 2, Genre3
       - Tag1, Tag2, Tag3

When it should display only the ones that match

Book 1- Genre 1, Genre 2
      -Tag1, Tag2

Book 2 - Genre3
        -Tag3

I would really love to do this without an ORM and it seems like its simple, but I cannot find a lot of resources on it without an ORM. Also any articles or examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you test your SQL statements against the database for a particular book id to ensure they are returning the expected results?

Comment: They are returning all the tags and genres just not for the specific book

Comment: then it's a problem with the sql statement.  Maybe its something to do with the type of join you used, Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549/1462656

Comment: I use a left outer join and it returns all the related items it just doesn't place them properly on the book they belong to